# How to unmarshall akka http request entity as array of strings?

Tags: json, scala, unmarshalling, akka-http

I am trying to unmarshall a post request payload as array of strings, but it's failing with 400 bad request with the error:

> The request content was malformed: Expected String as JsString, but
> got
> {"application":{"applicationRevision":{"string":"27904"},"applicationVersion":"india","id":"132231","name":"appTest"},"guest":{"session":"12bvg","systemTime":"2021-08-24T21:19:13.282Z","visitorId":"abc"}}

Body of the post request:

```
[{"application":{"applicationRevision":{"string":"27904"},"applicationVersion":"india","id":"132231","name":"appTest"},"guest":{"session":"12bvg","systemTime":"2021-08-24T21:19:13.282Z","visitorId":"abc"}}]
```

Below is the code:

```
def genericEventRoute: Route =
    path(basePath / version / "event" / "generic") {
      concat(
        post {
          entity(as[Array[String]]) { inputs =>
            extractClientIP { ip =>
              val ipAddress = ip.toOption.map(_.getHostAddress).getOrElse("unknown")
              system.log.info(s"ipAddress : $ipAddress")
              val operationPerformed: Future[IncomingIngest.Response] = incomingIngest.ask(IncomingIngest.ConsumeGenericEvent(inputs, ipAddress, _))
              onSuccess(operationPerformed) {
                case IncomingIngest.OK(message) => complete(StatusCodes.Created, List(`Content-Type`(`application/json`)), message)
                case IncomingIngest.KO(error) => complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, error)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      )
    }
```

How can I unmarshall into array of strings!! This is working if I send a String in the request by omitting ***[]*** and using ***entity(as[String])*** in the route. But, the payload I am supposed to get will be of array of strings. There is way to use **case class to unmarshall the payload** but in order to do that, all the fields inside the json have to be mapped which I don't want. The route should handle generic payload with array of strings. Can you please suggest a way to do so!

Comment: Well, you're not giving an array of string as input. If you want to do this you'll have to parse input as a `JsArray` and manually transform each item of the array to its string representation.

Comment: Thanks so much.. Is this the right way to convert: entity(as [JsArray]) { input => input.elements.map(ele => ele.toString()).   Or is there any better way to do this!!

Comment: I believe that's the good way indeed.

Comment: The best way is to create a class with the same "shape" as the JSON and parse directly into that structure. (Also remember that `Array` is a Java class not a Scala class, so prefer `List` or `Vector` unless you are interacting with Java).

Comment: Thanks Tim for pointing that out.. Yeah, that's the plan in the future to map every field properly as fields of case class. ```map()``` returns ```Vector[String]```, so I will use ```Vector``` only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incoming input is a JsArray, so will have to convert that to scala Vector/List of Strings and then process accordingly. Below is the code for that:

```
def genericEventRoute: Route =
    path(basePath / version / "event" / "generic") {
      concat(
        post {
          entity(as[JsArray]) { inputs =>
            extractClientIP { ip =>
              val ipAddress = ip.toOption.map(_.getHostAddress).getOrElse("unknown")
              system.log.info(s"ipAddress : $ipAddress")
              val arrInput = inputs.elements.map(ele => ele.toString())
              val operationPerformed: Future[IncomingIngest.Response] = incomingIngest.ask(IncomingIngest.ConsumeGenericEvent(arrInput, ipAddress, _))
              onSuccess(operationPerformed) {
                case IncomingIngest.OK(message) => complete(StatusCodes.Created, List(`Content-Type`(`application/json`)), message)
                case IncomingIngest.KO(error) => complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, error)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      )
    }
```

Remember that ***arrInput*** will be of type ***Vector[String]***. Though the best way would be to create a case class and parse the json directly into that as mentioned by Tim in the comment. But, for those use cases where incoming message does not follow any specific format, it might lead to parsing error. In this way, we can accept any incoming messages and push to downstream where the payload can be validated.